# Load not getting correct voltage and current with the circuit

Tags: power, dc

I am trying to power a DC fan (9WV1212J1002) with a 12V battery (RNG-BAT T-LFP-12-50). The path of the current will flow through three components: a 30A hall sensor (ACS712-30A), a load switch (TPS22810 WSON, 3A maximum), and a 5A hall sensor (ACS712-05B). The fan draws less than 1A with a voltage less than 4V with such setup. However, if I connect the fan directly to the battery, the fan draws ~2.9A at 12.9V. I also swapped the fan with a 6 ohm power resistor which is able to draw 2.15 A at 12.9V. My question is what can possibly affect the performance of the fan. All datasheet links are at the end.

[image]

Fan: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/471/San_Ace_120WV38_E-1282467.pdf

Battery: https://www.renogy.com/content/RNG-BATT-LFP-12-50/LFP50100170-Datasheet.pdf

Hall sensor: https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/0712.pdf

Load switch: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps22810.pdf?ts=1693330160406&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS22810

Comment: Where is voltage being dropped with the fan connected? What voltage readings do you get at each step in the path you described?